# Trigger on procedure call

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

my team and I started working on an legacy Oracle DB project. The whole business logic is written in PL/SQL without any documentation.

Now we want to get an overview of everything, especially which procedures / functions / packages get called. The problem is there are packages with suffix `_v1`, `_v2`, `_v1_org`, `_v2_new` and we have no idea which of them are really in use.

We don't want to change everything by adding a logging statement in the beginning of each function or procedure.

Is there some kind of trigger which fires on function call?

For example calling this code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION helloWorld AS
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello world!');
END;
```

would output something like this (line order is irrelevant)

```
Function "helloWorld" was called.
Hello world!
```

Comment: No, there is no trigger like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of DBMS_TRACE or DBMS_PROFILER to analyze what is happening.

Comment: This is very interesting. I'll try this approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The question is quite broad. In your place, I would start from the following:

- Identify enter points (if possible): which procedures/functions/packages are being called from a database client application.
- Add an initialisation section into packages:

  ```
  create or replace package body my_package as 
  ...
  -- add this after all functions, procedures, etc:
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Package my_package is initialised');
  end;
  ```

  This will allow you to define which packages are used. An initialisation section is executed once on the first package call in the session.
- Use `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` system view to check dependencies between database objects.
- Also, there is an [Audit](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/auditing.htm#DBSEG1023) feature, quite powerful. See example on [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:11397563179480). Maybe it is the best thing in your case.